# Separating a Build and Test on Jenkins

Tags: angularjs, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a angular application which i develop using source control ofcourse (gitlab), I recently integrated it with jenkins so that everytime i push to my git it triggers a build. In my jenkins i created a job that pretty much builds the application (installs dependencies) and runs test. Following is what my execute shell looks like in my job.

```
export npm_config_prefix=.npm/
export PATH=.npm/bin:$PATH
npm install -g bower grunt-cli
npm install
bower install
gulp test
```

Now the issue is that I do not want to build and run test as a same step i want them to seprate. So how do i achieve this  ? Do i create a new job and add `gulp test` in the execute shell of the  new job ? Or is there some other approach. I am new to jenkins and CI in general so was wondering what would be the approach in this situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, Jenkins is a super advanced shell script runner to take the boring part out of repeatable steps in the build process.

The next step is to hunt down plugins to do those steps for you in a cleaner way. This is where plugins come in

These is a [Node Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin) which will install npm packages outside the job so you don't have to do the `npm install -g` step every single job

You would want to keep the build step as shell

```
npm install
bower install
gulp test
```

I think that is your concern because you only need to run the job if the code has changed, including local dependencies. You could add a second shell step and just have the tests in there as it will run in the same workspace but all the build logs will be in one place

You didn't say what test runner your using but you will probably find a publisher step which will bring that into Jenkins for you [xUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) covers quite a few runners so might work for you

And this is the tutorial on [installing plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Howtoinstallplugins) into Jenkins

Comment: I guess xunit is for failing tests for some threshold values etc. That is fine but I am still confused about separating a build and a test. Because when i created a new job and just wrote gulp test in my second job i got an error saying gulp not found etc.

Comment: Is gulp a (dev) dependency in your package.json? then you'll need to do the `npm install` to get it or add it into the list of packages to install using the node plugin. `npm install` without the -g saves the packages into the node_modules directory on your project or workspace in Jenkins so this will start blank for a new project or if you clear out the workspace